# Should we define types for everything?

Tags: type-systems

Recently I got into a problem with the readability of my code.
I had a function that did an operation and returned a string representing the ID of this operation for future reference (a bit like OpenFile in Windows returning a handle). The user would use this ID later to start the operation and to monitor its finish.

The ID had to be a random string because of interoperability concerns. This created a method that had a very unclear signature like so:

```cs
public string CreateNewThing()
```

This makes the intent of the return type unclear. I thought to wrap this string in another type that makes its meaning clearer like thus:

```cs
public OperationIdentifier CreateNewThing()
```

The type will contain only the string and be used whenever this string is used.

It's obvious that the advantage of this way of operation is more type safety and clearer intent, but it also creates a lot more code and code that isn't very idiomatic. On the one hand I like the added safety, but it also creates a lot of clutter.

Do you think it is a good practice to wrap simple types in a class for safety reasons?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about Tiny Types. I played with it for a bit and wouldn't recommend it but it is a fun approach to think about. http://darrenhobbs.com/2007/04/11/tiny-types/

Comment: Once you use something like Haskell, you'll see how much using types helps. Types help ensure a correct program.

Comment: Even a dynamic language like Erlang benefits from a type system, which is why it has a typespec system and typechecking tool familiar to Haskellers despite being a dynamic language. Languages like C/C++ where the *real* type of anything is an integer that we agree with the compiler to treat a certain way, or Java where you almost sorta have types if you decide to pretend classes are types present either a semantic overloading problem in the language (is this a "class" or a "type"?) or type ambiguity (is this a "URL", "String" or "UPC"?). In the end, use whatever tools you can to disambiguate.

Comment: @Paul, this is exactly where my question comes from. In Haskell I'd easily create a file with 20 types that encapsulate all the primitive types. But C#/Java/OOP trend of the week all have overhead of creating these things. You could avoid some of it by using structs where appropriate and most of the time you don't really care for performance issues (compilers are dead[1][http://cr.yp.to/talks/2015.04.16/slides-djb-20150416-a4.pdf]). The performance issue I'm seeing is human in having to create all these types and maintain them, as called on by MainMa.

Comment: I'm not sure where the idea comes from that C++ has an overhead on types. With C++11, none of the compiler makers saw a problem in giving each lambda its own unique type. But TBH you can't really expect to find a lot of insight in a comment about the "C/C++ type system" as if the two share a type system.

Comment: FYI... what you are describing sounds very much like the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Comment: @JDB - no, it doesn't. Not even similar.

Comment: Java users will appreciate [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) and [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) - two powerful tools for quickly defining this sort of value types.

Comment: I know this isn't really what you're asking, but if at all possible (which it may not be in your situation), I would return the NewlyCreatedThing itself rather than some string identifier I would have to create and maintain myself. Your code looks Java-y, it will create a reference for you.

Comment: And yes, Types For Everything®

Comment: @dimo414 Java users will also appreciate [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for reducing the verbosity of that language.

Answer (score 159):

Primitives, such as `string` or `int`, have no meaning in a business domain. A direct consequence of this is that **you may mistakenly use an URL when a product ID is expected, or use quantity when expecting price**.

This is also why [Object Calisthenics challenge](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf) features primitives wrapping as one of its rules:

> **Rule 3: Wrap all primitives and Strings**
>
> In the Java language, int is a primitive, not a real object, so it obeys different rules than objects. It is used with a syntax that isn’t object-oriented. More importantly, an int on its own is just a scalar, so it has no meaning. When a method takes an int as a parameter, the method name needs to do all of the work of expressing the intent. If the same method takes an Hour as a parameter, it’s much easier to see what’s going on.

The same document explains that there is an additional benefit:

> Small objects like Hour or Money also give us an **obvious place to put behavior that would otherwise have been littered around other classes**.

Indeed, when primitives are used, it's usually extremely difficult to track the exact location of the code related to those types, often leading to severe **code duplication**. If there is `Price: Money` class, it is natural to find the range checking inside. If, instead, a `int` (worse, a `double`) is used to store product prices, who should validate the range? The product? The rebate? The cart?

Finally, a third benefit not mentioned in the document is the ability to change relatively easy the underlying type. If today my `ProductId` has `short` as its underlying type and later I need to use `int` instead, chances are the code to change will not span the entire code base.

The drawback—and the same argument applies to every rule of Object Calisthenics exercise—is that if quickly becomes **too overwhelming to create a class for everything**. If `Product` contains `ProductPrice` which inherits from `PositivePrice` which inherits from `Price` which in turn inherits from `Money`, this is not clean architecture, but rather a complete mess where in order to find a single thing, a maintainer should open a few dozen files every time.

Another point to consider is the cost (in terms of lines of code) of creating additional classes. If the wrappers are immutable (as they should be, usually), it means that, if we take C#, you have to have, within the wrapper at least:

- The property getter,
- Its backing field,
- A constructor which assigns the value to the backing field,
- A custom `ToString()`,
- XML documentation comments (which makes *a lot* of lines),
- A `Equals` and a `GetHashCode` overrides (also a lot of LOC).

and eventually, when relevant:

- A [DebuggerDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute,
- An override of `==` and `!=` operators,
- Eventually an overload of the implicit conversion operator to seamlessly convert to and from the encapsulated type,
- Code contracts (including the invariant, which is a rather long method, with its three attributes),
- Several converters which will be used during XML serialization, JSON serialization or storing/loading a value to/from a database.

A hundred LOC for a simple wrapper makes it quite prohibitive, which is also why you may be completely sure of the long-term profitability of such wrapper. The notion of scope [explained by Thomas Junk](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/281832/6605) is particularly relevant here. Writing a hundred LOCs to represent a `ProductId` used all over your code base looks quite useful. Writing a class of this size for a piece of code which makes three lines within a single method is much more questionable.

**Conclusion:**

- Do wrap primitives in classes which have a meaning in a business domain of the application when (1) it helps reducing mistakes, (2) reduces the risk of code duplication or (3) helps changing the underlying type later.
- Don't wrap automatically every primitive you find in your code: there are many cases where using `string` or `int` is perfectly fine.

In practice, in `public string CreateNewThing()`, returning an instance of `ThingId` class instead of `string` might help, but you may also:

- Return an instance of `Id<string>` class, that is an object of generic type indicating that the underlying type is a string. You have your benefit of readability, without the drawback of having to maintain a lot of types.
- Return an instance of `Thing` class. If the user only needs the ID, this can easily be done with:

  ```
  var thing = this.CreateNewThing();
  var id = thing.Id;
  ```

Comment: I think the power to freely change the underlying type is important here. It's a string today, but perhaps a GUID or long tomorrow. Creating the type wrapper hides that information away leading to fewer changes down the road. ++ Good answer here.

Comment: In the case of money, make sure the currency is either included in the Money object, or your whole program uses the same one (which then should be documented).

Comment: I disagree about the long chain of inheritance being automatically messy.  Sometimes the taxonomy of what you're modeling requires it and there's no sense in duplicating code to meet some arbitrary maximum acceptable depth.   If you write code that uses `ProductPrice`, your understanding of that class should begin and end with its interface and its implementation shouldn't your concern.

Comment: @Blrfl: while there are valid cases where deep inheritance is necessary, I usually see such inheritance in overdesigned code written with no attention to readability, resulting from compulsive pay-by-LOC attitude. Thus the negative character of this part of my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes...  Silly me for thinking people might behave rationally.  :-)

Comment: @Blrfl I disagree with your initial disagreement. Inheritance, I find, is often applied as a catch all for code reusage. I actually find it often better to apply other patterns such as composition, leading to clearer code.

Comment: @ArTs:  That's the "let's condemn the tool because some people use it the wrong way" argument.

Comment: @MainMa An example for where meaning might have avoided a costly error: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure

Comment: @Blrfl its not. I believe that deep nested inheritance is a code smell. Like all code smells there are legitimate reasons for it to exist, but the vast majority of the time, the actual reason is a bad one. Your example case of `ProductPrice` is most definitely a code smell. You'll end up creating a `ServicePrice` and then a common base class of `SellablePrice`...

Comment: @ArTs:  The threshold number for "too deep" is...?

Comment: > Rule 3: Wrap all primitives and Strings `CountType count = countItems(items); int numberOfItems = count.getValue();`

Comment: @cbojar $330' million to be exact...

Comment: I like the idea of working with objects instead of working with ids. It gives a higher level of abstraction, and can improve readability a lot. If you can do that, you have no more need for a class representing the id.

Comment: Remember that Object Calisthenics is an exercise an should not be applied everywhere. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/202669/160830

Answer (score 62):

I would use the *scope* as a rule of thumb: The narrower the scope of generating and consuming such `values` is, the less likely you have to create an object representing this value.

Say you have the following *pseudocode*

```
id = generateProcessId();
doFancyOtherstuff();
job.do(id);
```

then the scope is very limited and I would see no sense in making it a type.
But say, you generate this value in one layer and pass it to another layer (or even another object), then it would make perfect sense to create a type for that.

Comment: A very good point. Explicit types are an important tool for *communicating intent*, which is especially important across object and service boundaries.

Comment: +1 although if you haven't yet refactored all the code of `doFancyOtherstuff()` into a subroutine, you might think the `job.do(id)` reference is not local enough to keep as a simple string.

Comment: This is totally true!  It's the case when you have a private method where you know that the outside world will never use the method. After that, you can think a little bit more when the class is protected and after that when the class is public but not part of a public api. Scope scope scope and a lot of art to place the line at the good position between to much primitive and to much custom types.

Answer (score 34):

Static type systems are all about preventing incorrect uses of data.

There are obvious examples of types doing this:

- you can't get the month of a UUID
- you can't multiply two strings.

There are more subtle examples

- you can't pay for something using the length of desk
- you can't make an HTTP request using someone's name as the URL.

We may be tempted to use `double` for both  price and length, or use a `string` for both a name and a URL. But doing that subverts our awesome type system, and  allows these misuses to pass the language's static checks.

Getting pound-seconds confused with Newton-seconds can have [poor results at runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure).

---

This is particularly a problem with strings. They frequently become the "universal data type".

We are used to primarily text interfaces with computers, and we often extend these *human interfaces* (UIs) to *programming interfaces* (APIs). We think of 34.25 as the characters *34.25*. We think of a date as the characters *05-03-2015*. We think of a UUID as the characters *75e945ee-f1e9-11e4-b9b2-1697f925ec7b*.

But this mental model harms API abstraction.

> The words or the language, as they are written or spoken, do not seem to play any role in my mechanism of thought.
>
> Albert Einstein

Similarly, textual representations should not play any role in designing types and APIs. Beware the `string`! (and other overly generic "primitive" types)

---

***Types* communicate "what operations make sense."**

For example, I once worked on a client to an HTTP REST API. REST, properly done, use hypermedia entities, which have hyperlinks pointing to related entities. In this client, not only were the entities typed (e.g. User, Account, Subscription), the links to those entities were also typed (UserLink, AccountLink, SubscriptionLink). The links were little more than wrappers around `Uri`, but the separate types made it impossible to try to use an AccountLink to fetch a User. Had everything been plain `Uri`s -- or even worse, `string` -- these mistakes would only be found at runtime.

Likewise, in your situation, you have data that is used for only one purpose: to identify an `Operation`. It shouldn't be used for anything else, and we shouldn't be trying to identify `Operation`s with random strings we've made up. Creating a separate class adds readability and safety to your code.

---

Of course, all good things can be used in excess. Consider

1. how much clarity it adds to your code
2. how often it is used

If a "type" of data (in the abstract sense) is used frequently, for distinct purposes, and between code interfaces, it is a very good candidate for being a separate class, at the expense of verbosity.

Comment: "strings often become the 'universal' data type" - that's the origin of the tongue-in-cheek "stringly typed languages" moniker.

Comment: @MSalters, ha ha, very nice.

Comment: And of course, what does `05-03-2015` *mean* [when interpreted as a date](https://xkcd.com/1179/)?

Answer (score 11):

> Do you think it is a good practice to wrap simple types in a class for safety reasons?

**Sometimes.**

This is one of those cases where you need to weigh the problems that may arise from using a `string` instead of a more concrete `OperationIdentifier`. What are their severity? What is their likeliness?

Then you need to consider the cost of using the other type. How painful is it to use? How much work is it to make?

In some cases, you'll save yourself time and effort by having a nice concrete type to work against. In others, it won't be worth the trouble.

In general, I think that this sort of thing should be done more than it is today. If you have an entity that means something in your domain, it is good to have that as its own type, since that entity is more likely to change/grow with the business.

Answer (score 10):

I generally agree that many times you should create a type for primitives and strings, but because the above answers recommend creating a type in most cases, I'll list a few reasons why/when not to:

- Performance. I must refer to actual languages here. In C#, if a client ID is a short and you wrap it in a class - you've just created a lot of overhead: memory, since it's now 8 bytes on a 64 bit system and speed since now it's allocated on the heap.
- When you make assumptions on the type. If a client ID is a short and you have some logic that packs it in some manner - you usually already make assumptions on the type. In all those places you now have to break the abstraction. If it's one spot, it's not a big deal, if it's all over the place, you might find that half the time you're using the primitive.
- Because not every language has typedef. And for languages that don't and code that's already written, making such a change could be a big task that might even introduce bugs (but everyone has a test suite with good coverage, right?).
- In some cases it *reduces* readability. *How do I print this? How do I validate this? Should I be checking for null?* Are all questions that requires you drill into the definition of the type.

Comment: Surely if the wrapper type is a struct rather than a class, then a `short` (for example) has the same cost wrapped or unwrapped. (?)

Comment: Would it not be good design for a type to encapsulate its own validation? Or to create a helper type to validate it?

Comment: Packing or munging unnecessarily is an anti-pattern. Information should flow transparently through application code, except where transformation is _explicitly & genuinely necessary_. Types are good since they typically substitute a small amount of good code, located in a single place, for large amounts of poor implementation splattered all over the system.

Answer (score 9):

No, you should not define types (classes) for "everything".

But, as other answers state, it *often* is useful to do so. You should develop – consciously, if possible – a feeling or sense of too-much-friction due to the *absence* of a suitable type or class, as you write, test, and maintain your code. For me, the onset of too-much-friction is when I want to consolidate multiple primitive values as a single value or when I need to validate the values (i.e. determine which of all possible values of the primitive type correspond to valid values of the 'implied type').

I've found considerations such as what you've posed in your question to be responsible for *too much* design in my code. I've developed a habit of deliberately avoiding writing any more code than necessary. Hopefully you're writing good (automated) tests for your code – if you are, then you can easily refactor your code and add types or classes **if doing so provides net benefits for the ongoing development and maintenance of your code**.

[Telastyn's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/281828/2839) and [Thomas Junk's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/281832/2839) both make a very good point about the context and usage of the relevant code. If you're using a value inside a single block of code (e.g. method, loop, `using` block) then it's fine to just use a primitive type. It's even fine to use a primitive type if you're using a set of values repeatedly and in many other places. But the more frequently and widely you're using a set of values, and the less closely that set of values corresponds to the values represented by the primitive type, the more you should consider encapsulating the values in a class or type.

Answer (score 5):

Idea behind wrapping primitive types,

- To establish domain specific language
- Limit mistakes done by users by passing incorrect values

Obviously it would be very difficult and not practical to do it everywhere, but it's important to wrap the types where required,

For example if you have the class Order,

```cs
Order
{
   long OrderId { get; set; }
   string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
   double Amount { get; set; }
   string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
```

The important properties to look up an Order is mostly OrderId and InvoiceNumber. And the Amount and CurrencyCode are closely related, where if someone change the CurrencyCode without changing the Amount the Order no longer can be considered as valid.

So, only wrapping OrderId, InvoiceNumber and introducing a composite for currency makes sense in this scenario and probably wrapping description makes no sense. So preferred result could look like,

```cs
    Order
    {
       OrderIdType OrderId { get; set; }
       InvoiceNumberType InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
       string Description { get; set; }
       Currency Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

So there is no reason to wrap everything, but things that actually matters.

Answer (score 5):

On the surface it looks like all you need to do is identify an operation.

Additionally you say what an operation is supposed to do:

> to **start the operation** [and] to **monitor its finish**

You say it in a way as if this is "just how the identification is used", but I would say these are properties describing an operation.
That sounds like a type definition to me, [there's even a pattern called the "command pattern" that fits very well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

It says

> the command pattern [...] is used to encapsulate all information needed to **perform an action** or **trigger an event at a later time**.

I think this is very similar compared to what you want to do with your operations. (Compare the phrases I made bold in both quotes) Instead of returning a string, return an identifier for an `Operation` in the abstract sense, a pointer to an object of that class in oop for example.

Regarding the comment

> It would be wtf-y to call this class a command and then not have the logic inside it.

No it wouldn't. 
Remember that **patterns are very abstract**, so abstract in fact that they are somewhat meta. That is, they often abstract the programming itself and not some real world concept. The command pattern is an abstraction of a function call. (or method) As if somebody hit the pause button right after passing the values of the parameters and right before execution, to be resumed later.

The following is considering oop, but the motivation behind it should hold true for any paradigm. I like to give some reasons why placing the logic into the command can be considered a bad thing.

1. If you had all that logic in the command, it would be bloated and messy. You
   would be thinking "oh well, all this functionality should be in
   separate classes." You would **refactor** the logic out of the
   command.
2. If you had all that logic in the command, it would be hard to test
   and get in the way when testing. "Holy crap, why do I have to use
   this command nonsense? **I only want to test if this function** spits
   out 1 or not, I don't want to call it later, I want to test it now!"
3. If you had all that logic in the command, it wouldn't make too much
   sense to report back when finished. If you think about a function to
   be executed synchronously by default, it makes no sense to be
   notified when it finishes executing. Maybe you are starting another
   thread because your operation is actually to render avatar to cinema
   format (may need additional thread on raspberry pi), maybe you have
   to fetch some data from a server, ...whatever it is, if there's a
   reason for reporting back when finished, it could be because there's
   some asynchronousity (is that a word?) going on. I think running a
   thread or contacting a server is logic that should not be in your
   command. This is somewhat of a meta argument and maybe controversial. If you think it makes no sense, please tell me in the comments.

To recap: the command pattern allows you to wrap functionality
 into an object, to be executed later. For the sake of modularity (functionality exists regardless of being executed via command or not), testability (functionality should be testable without command) and all those other buzz words that essentially express the demand to write good code, you would not put the actual logic into the command.

---

Because patterns are abstract, it can be hard to come up with good real world metaphors. Here's an attempt:

"Hey grandma, could you please hit the record button on the TV at 12 so I don't miss the simpsons on channel 1?"

My grandma does not know what happens technically when she hits that record button. The logic is elsewhere (in the TV). And that's a good thing. The functionality is encapsulated and information is hidden from the command, it is a user of the API, not necessarily part of the logic ...oh jeez I'm babbling buzz words again, I better finish this edit now.

Comment: You are correct, I haven't thought about it like that. But the command pattern isn't a 100% good fit because the logic of the operation is encapsulated in another class and I can't put it inside the object that is the Command. It would be wtf-y to call this class a command and then not have the logic inside it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Consider returning an Operation, not an OperationIdentifier.  This is similar to the C# TPL where you return a Task or Task<T>.  @Ziv: You say "the logic of the operation is encapsulated in another class."  But does that really mean you can't also provide it from here as well?

Comment: @Ziv I beg to differ. Take a look at the reasons I added to my answer and see if they make any sense to you. =)

Answer (score 4):

Unpopular opinion:

**You should usually not define a new type!**

Defining a new type to wrap a primitive or a basic class is sometimes called defining a pseudo-type. IBM describes this as a bad practice [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02216/) (they focus specifically on misuse with generics in this case).

***Pseudo types make common library functionality useless.***

Java's Math functions can work with all number primitives. But if you define a new class Percentage (wrapping a double that can be in the range 0~1) all these functions are useless and need to be wrapped by classes that (even worse) need to know about the internal representation of the Percentage class.

***Pseudo types go viral***

When making multiple libraries you will often find that these pseudotypes go viral. If you use the, above mentioned, Percentage class in one library you will either need to convert it at the library boundary (losing all safety/meaning/logic/other reason you had for creating that type) or you will have to make these classes accessible to the other library as well. Infecting the new library with your types where a simple double might have sufficed.

***Take away message***

As long as the type you wrap does not need a lot of business logic I would advice against wrapping it in a pseudo class. You should only wrap a class if there are serious business constraints. In other cases naming your variables correctly should go a long way in conveying meaning.

An example:

A `uint` can perfectly represent a UserId, we can keep using Java's built in operators for `uint`s (such as ==) and we do not need business logic to protect the 'internal state' of the user id.

Comment: Agree. all the programming philosophy is fine, but in practice you have to make it work as well

Comment: If you've seen any adverts for loans to the poorest people in the UK, you will find that Percentage to wrap a double in the range 0..1 doesn't work...

Comment: In C / C++ / Objective C you can use a typedef, which gives you just a new name for an existing primitive type. On the other hand, your code should work no matter what the underlying type, for example if I change OrderId from uint32_t to uint64_t (because I need to process more than 4 billion orders).

Comment: I will not downvote you for your bravery, but pseudotypes and the types defined in the toprated answer are different. Those are types that are business specific. Psuedotypes are types that are still generic.

Comment: @gnasher729: C++11 has also user-defined literals that make the wrapping process very sweet for the user: **Distance d = 36.0_mi + 42.0_km;** . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919277.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As with all tips, knowing when to apply the rules is the skill. If you create your own types in a type-driven language you get type checking. So generally that is going to be a good plan.

**NamingConvention** is key to readability. The two combined can convey intention clearly. 
But /// is still useful.

So yes, I would say create many own types when their lifetime is beyond a class boundary. Also consider the use of both `Struct` and `Class`, not always Class.

Comment: What does `///` mean?

Comment: /// is the documentation comment in C# that allows intellisense to show the documentation of the signature at the call method point. Consider the best way to document code. Can be farmed by tools and offer reach intellisence behaviour. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkxs89c5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx